# Bazel BUILD files conflicts with a build/ folder

Tags: bazel

I am migrating my Cmake project to Bazel. At the root of my project is a `build` folder that I use to run Cmake.

To migrate to [Bazel](https://bazel.build), I need to create a `BUILD` file at the root of my project. However, on macOS, I cannot create it due to the presence of my `build` folder.

Can I use a different name for Bazel's `BUILD` files? Or should I get rid of my `build` folder?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Bazel also supports using BUILD.bazel as the filename, which should resolve this issue (BUILD.bazel is preferred if both BUILD.bazel and BUILD exist).

Please try using that and see if it helps!