# Bazel ignore subdirectory on full build

Tags: bazel

In my repository I have some files with the name *"build"* (automatically generated and/or imported, spread around elsewhere from where I have my bazel build files). These seem to be interpreted by Bazel as its BUILD files, and fail the full build I try to run with `bazel build //...`

Is there some way I can tell Bazel in a settings configuration file to ignore certain directories altogether? Or perhaps specify the build file names as something other than *BUILD*, like *BUILD.bazel*?

Or are my options:

- To banish the name *build* from the entire repository.
- To add a gigantic `--deleted_packages=<...>` to every run of build.
- To not use full builds, instead specifying explicit targets.

Comment: Saw https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43205637/bazel-build-files-conflicts-with-a-build-folder?rq=1 - Seems to be a good solution, but will it then ignore other build files elswhere?

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44622875/bazel-how-to-recursively-glob-deleted-packages-to-ignore-maven-outputs seems to be similar, will try that solution.

Comment: "but will it then ignore other build files elswhere?" - no

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bazel BUILD files conflicts with a build/ folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43205637/bazel-build-files-conflicts-with-a-build-folder)

Comment: @kristina Not really a problem with collisions, but rather that there are some new files called "build" elsewhere in the repository, which Bazel assumes it should mess with. As Adam said renaming to "BUILD.bazel" is not a fix since I don't have BUILD files in the same folders as the problematic build ones.

Comment: Do you know where I can find some information on what filenames Bazel uses, and rules for which it will prefer (like BUILD.bazel)?

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a duplicate of the two questions you linked, but to expand on what you asked about in your comment:

You don't have to rename them BUILD.bazel, my suggestion is to add an empty BUILD.bazel to those directories.  So you'd end up with:

```
my-project/
  BUILD
  src/
    build/
      stuff-bazel-shouldn't-mess-with
    BUILD.bazel  # Empty
```

Then Bazel will check for targets in BUILD.bazel, see that there are none, and won't try to parse the `build/` directory.

And there is a distressing lack of documentation about BUILD vs. BUILD.bazel, at least that I could find.

Comment: This is a solution so long as the path is not my-project/generated/generated-thing/build, since then it is more difficult to add the BUILD.bazel to the correct folders. Could not find documentation about names myself either. Do you know about the site conventions - do I accept this answer?